# How to make Python find a file in script mode?

Tags: python, python-import, filepath, importerror

I'm currently trying to import Python files downloaded from external sources into my code. This has worked perfectly fine within the Python shell, but when using the exact same code within an IDLE file, Python is unable to find the file in the given directory, even though it does find the directory itself.

My aim is to import the Python Natural Language Toolkit, which requires the module 'six'. So I've imported first 'six', then NLTK into a shell.
I've then tried to repeat the same code within script mode.

**INTERACTIVE MODE**

```
>>> import os 
>>> path = "C:/Users/henri/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages" 
>>> os.chdir(path) 
>>> os.getcwd()
```

Result:

```
'C:\\Users\\henri\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\pip\\_vendor\\urllib3\\packages'  <br/>
```

```
>>> import six 
>>> dir(six)
```

Result:

```
['BytesIO', 'Iterator', 'MAXSIZE', 'Module_six_moves_urllib', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_error', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_request', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_response', 'Module_six_moves_urllib_robotparser', 'MovedAttribute', 'MovedModule', 'PY2', 'PY3', 'PY34', 'StringIO', '_LazyDescr', '_LazyModule', '_MovedItems', '_SixMetaPathImporter', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_add_doc', '_assertCountEqual', '_assertRaisesRegex', '_assertRegex', '_func_closure', '_func_code', '_func_defaults', '_func_globals', '_import_module', '_importer', '_meth_func', '_meth_self', '_moved_attributes', '_urllib_error_moved_attributes', '_urllib_parse_moved_attributes', '_urllib_request_moved_attributes', '_urllib_response_moved_attributes', '_urllib_robotparser_moved_attributes', 'absolute_import', 'add_metaclass', 'add_move', 'advance_iterator', 'assertCountEqual', 'assertRaisesRegex', 'assertRegex', 'b', 'binary_type', 'byte2int', 'callable', 'class_types', 'create_bound_method', 'create_unbound_method', 'exec_', 'functools', 'get_function_closure', 'get_function_code', 'get_function_defaults', 'get_function_globals', 'get_method_function', 'get_method_self', 'get_unbound_function', 'indexbytes', 'int2byte', 'integer_types', 'io', 'iterbytes', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'iterlists', 'itertools', 'itervalues', 'moves', 'next', 'operator', 'print_', 'python_2_unicode_compatible', 'raise_from', 'remove_move', 'reraise', 'string_types', 'sys', 'text_type', 'types', 'u', 'unichr', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues', 'with_metaclass', 'wraps']
```

**SCRIPT MODE**

```
import os 

# importing six

path="C:/Users/henri/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/lib/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/packages" 
os.chdir(path)  
os.getcwd() 
print(os.getcwd()) 

import six 

dir(six)
```

And this is the resulting error message when trying to run this code:

> RESTART: C:\Users\henri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\importing_nltk_file_2.py   
>   C:\Users\henri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\packages  
>   Traceback (most recent call last):  
>     File "C:\Users\henri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\importing_nltk_file_2.py", line 13, in 
>       import six  
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

So, does anyone have an idea why Python can't find 'six', although the directory is unmistakeably correct?

Comment: Do you have different versions of Python running on your laptop ? Plus, just to be sure :  Can you confirm that the `ModuleNotFoundError` occurs when you try to import `nltk` ?

Comment: Kindly check if you are using same python version in IDE which you are using in the shell?

Comment: You could consider adding the location of the module via sys.path.append(path).

Comment: Check to make sure your python version is the same if you used pip and running python 3.x you might need to run pip3 and it may work .... If it still doesn't work perhaps pip uninstall six then install it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you run a python script all import statements are run first and then other parts of your code are executed. So, import six is executed before os.chdir() and hence, the error

Comment: Thanks to everyone who's contributed to my question! I've been able to fix the problem by adding `sys.path.append(path)`.